# Add a 'wait' in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

Is there a way to do something like the following, to delay the `location.reload()` ?

```
$('.thank-you').show().wait(1000); // wait 1s before doing the reload
location.reload();
```

Comment: you can wrap it with a setTimeout

Comment: You are likely looking for `$.delay`, [more info here](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Comment: `.delay()` is only used to delay effects in the jQuery effects queue. It is not a replacement for `setTimeOut`

Comment: @Derek - using `queue` to create queues in jQuery makes `delay` available for more than animations. It's just that it's usually more complicated to do so, then to just use `setTimeout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery it's called [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) not `wait()`

However in plain javascript you have timeouts, and it looks more like that's what you really want

```
$('.thank-you').show()

setTimeout(function {
    location.reload();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The location.reload() will fire immediately as delay() is asynchronous.

Comment: How would I achieve my above objective then? To 'delay' 1 second after the "Thank you" message appears, before the reload() event if fired ?

Comment: You can pass a function to show() that fires upon completion. You might want to put your location.reload() in a setTimeout like this: $('.thank-you').show(0, function() { setTimeout(location.reload, 1000);  })